# Moving values between lockfree lists

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, lock-free

## Background

I am trying to design and implement lock-free hashmap using chaining method in C++. Each hash table cell is supposed to contain lockfree list. To enable resizing, my data structure is supposed to contain two arrays - small one which is always available and a bigger one for resizing, when the smaller one is no longer sufficient. When the bigger one is created I would like the data stored in small one to be transfered to bigger one by one, whenever any thread does something with the data structure (adds element, searches or removes one). When all data is transfered, the bigger array is moved in place of smaller and the latter one is deleted. The cycle repeats whenever the array needs to be enlarged.

## Problem

As mentioned before, each array is supposed to conatin lists in cells. I am trying to find a way to transfer a value or node from one lockfree list to another in such a manner that would keep value visible in any (or both) of the lists. It is needed to ensure that search in hash map won't give the user false negatives. So my questions are:

1. Is such lockfree list implementation possible?
2. If so, what would be the general concept of such list and "moving node/value" operation? I would be thankful for any pseudocode, C++ code or scientific article describing it.

Comment: I do not see this question as specific to C++, so I removed the tag.

Comment: @SergeyA fair enough, I was hasitating too. Even though there are some specific for C and C++ parallelism problems (like memory management)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to resize the array, while maintaining the lock-free progress guarantees, you will need to use operation descriptors. Once the resize starts, add a descriptor that contains references to the old and the new arrays.

On any operation (add, search, or remove):

- Add operation, search the old array, if the element already exists, then move the element to the new array before returning. Indicate, with a descriptor or a special null value that the element has already been moved so that other threads don't attempt the move again
- Search, search the old array and move the element as indicated above.
- Remove - Remove too will have to search the old array first.

Now the problem is that you will have a thread that has to verify that the move is complete, so that you can remove the descriptor and free up the old array. To maintain lock-freedom, you will need to have all active threads attempt to do this validation, thus it becomes very expensive.

You can look at:

- https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2611495
- https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3210408